# How to change this robots meta php data

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a client whos robot meta data is being set to "content=none" but I want to change it to enable robots.

I need to change this part of the header.php file but I'm not really familiar with php:

```
<?php if ( of_get_option('sc_enablerobot')== '1') { ?>
<!-- robots -->
<meta name="robots" content="<?php echo of_get_option('sc_metabots')  ?>" />
<meta name="googlebot" content="<?php echo of_get_option('sc_metagooglebot')  ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

I'm not sure what the sc_enablerobot variable is but I'm sure I can just change this so I don't have to refer to it. How do I change this code to enable the robots which will use the following meta data?:

```
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow"> 
<meta name="googlebot" content="index,follow">
```

Comment: Just remove the php code inside of content and replace it with what you want it to be.

Comment: Do a project-wide search on the string in your IDE and change it

Comment: I would imagine there is an option in wordpress to manage this based on the fact there is a variable there.

Comment: Seems to be part of this plugin: http://wptheming.com/options-framework-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

This functions are from the options plugin framework.  Here's is a tutorial on how to use it: [link](http://wptheming.com/options-framework-plugin/)

You'll have edit the `options.php` file in the plugin's folder.  The functions are grabbing the value from there.

Comment: I changed it to:   <?php if ( of_get_option('sc_enablerobot')== '1') { ?>
  
  <!-- robots -->
  <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="index,follow"> 
  <?php } ?>

It works, I don't see a problem with that, it should be ok right?

Comment: Assuming you don't want to manage it via the plugin in the future, yes.

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth noting that having both robot meta tags is redundant as Googlebot adheres to both robot meta tags. The only time you will use both robot meta tags is when your specifically trying to tell Googlebot something.